# Deprecated: mysql_real_escape_string(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

> I'm actually looking for an alternative to mysql_real_escape_string to
>   solve this error.
>   in php 5.4 it worked perfectly but no longer in php 5.5

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
// in class user
public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue)
        {   
            switch($p_sProperty)
            {    
// this is marked as the error
case "Email":
             $this->Email = **mysql_real_escape_string**($p_vValue); 
                break;
}
}
```

Comment: You can't mis `mysql_*` functions and `mysqli_*` functions...

Comment: If you're looking for a quick answer to the OP's question, then this is a valid question: the other one (that this is marked as a duplicate of) eventually addresses the issue, but comes from a different question and is quite involved.

Comment: A simple alternative is the function:

`addslashes`

Example:

`addslashes("a string with double quote ")`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You using MySQLi so use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`:

```
$this->Email = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($p_vValue);
```